# How to use PayPal mass payments with Django?

Tags: python, django, paypal, masspay

I have figured out how to receive payments using `django-paypal` library from python, but i couldn't find the feature that would send the funds to other users.

Although there wasn't such feature in `django-paypal`, i have found out PayPal's mass payments from API, but i couldn't understand how would i use it in Python.

---

So for example, i know the email of user, how could i send 5$ by just email information.

Code Example:

```
import random
User = "example@example.com"
import MassivePay


def Sender():
    MassivePay.sendto = random.choice(User)
    MassivePay.send(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=Sender)
    p.start()
```

I know it's too easy example demonstrated in code, but how could it be seriously done in Django? Is there any library specially designed for framework? Or Python itself? If so how can i use it? Does masspay work with Django at all?

Comment: check https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK you might find something useful. If you can't find any python library you can always go REST.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply @alphiii ! can i use `paypalrestsdk.Payment` for paying?

Comment: I am using this sdk to develop a system for mass payments with paypal. Must say, there is a massive room for muckups here, as paypal's system is rather complex :( Did you successfully implement a system?

Comment: @andyw I unfortunately could not. There are specific requirements that must be satisfied. View my comment below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48366391/6083655).