# Utilize Paypal API to send a single payment to email

Tags: paypal

Say i've had a cash out page on my website that included Paypal cash out system where user would specify his/her email. What is the new updated way to send single payment to the specified email? Which API would i need to use?

I've been researching it approximately for an hour and i can't seem to find a proper method, I've seen this:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
  -d '{
  "sender_batch_header":{
    "sender_batch_id":"2014021801",
    "email_subject":"You have a payout!",
    "recipient_type":"EMAIL"
  },
  "items":[
    {
      "recipient_type":"EMAIL",
      "amount":{
        "value":"1.0",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "note":"Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id":"201403140001",
      "receiver":"anybody01@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}' - [from here][1]
```

But i can't seem to understand how to obtain `sender_batch_header`. I think this method is used for different purposes.

---

So what's the newest working method to send payments by paypal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the **Payouts API** is the API that's substituting the previous **Mass Payments API**, used to send many payouts synchronously or asynchronously to different beneficiaries.

Basically imagine a company that uses Paypal to pay his employees and has an internal application which every month sends everyone their salaries.

As you can read in the docs:

> **Note:** Payouts are available everywhere that Mass Payments are
>   available. Any payouts that you send through the Payouts API appear as
>   Mass Payments in your PayPal account and in Mass Payment reports.

Now, regarding the `sender_batch_header`, it basically **allows you to track payments by batches** so you don't accidentally send the same batch twice.

Let's say every Christmas, the same company I mentioned above, likes to send a small gift to their employees, something like an extra 500$. If by some chance the client application which the company has developed to send the payments has a bug and doesn't log extraordinary payments in the calendar, the CEO might get confused and try to send it twice. In that case, Paypal refuses to accept another payout with the same `sender_batch_Id`.

Furthermore, you can **retrieve the information of a certain batch** through its `sender_batch_Id` through the following endpoint:

```
/v1/payments/payouts/payout_batch_id
```

That way you can know if the batch has already been processed and your employees have it in their Paypal accounts, if it has been denied, or whatever you need.

If you need more information, I found the API to be fairly well documented: [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and apologies for late response. I've contacted Paypal numerous times and found out the only way to enable Payouts API is to have business support or manager feature. They require more than 5k pounds of total income of accounts for Buss. department and 40k pounds of total income for manager. This really is unfortunate for starting companies, I gusss web scraping is the only way.

Comment: @ShellRox I wasn't aware of those limitations! Thanks for the info though :)